# I have a set of Blinds.com black out shades. I can't seem to find the correct brackets

Tags: windows, blinds

[image: Side view]I have a set of blinds.com that is missing the 3-4 brackets that were supposed[image: end view] to come with it.  Blinds.com has "mailed out" the brackets twice already. I put brackets because they wouldn't give me a tracking number. Anyway, it's been 2 months and I am tired of waiting for them to get me brackets.  Does anyone know or has a picture of what they are supposed to be?

ZC1-B1-688
UltraCel 3/8" Double
Blackout CLDayNight

Comment: I use "fixmyblinds.com" when I need random unnamed parts for my blinds.  Send them an email with your pics and they'll tell you if they have the part you want.

Comment: Yes I did send pictures to them and they said they don't have anything.  I am hoping someone on this forum has these same blinds and can at least give me a picture of the correct bracket.